# maximising the frequency of mode.

Tags: statistics, discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics, dynamic-programming

I have `4` numbers `5,5,3,1`. Now I have the number `5`, which I can distribute in any manner to these 4 numbers. Now I have to find the maximum possible frequency of the mode from all the newly formed sequences. For instance I can form `5,5,5,1`.(give `2` to `3`)
Note that all the numbers might not be distributed.

What is the general approach of such problem?
Note that I just the maximum possible frequency of the sequence.

Comment: What do you mean by "distribute"? And what does "(give $2$ to $3$)" mean?

Comment: I mean lets say I have 4 children and each have 5,5,3,1 chocolates. I have 5 chocolates and would like everyone to have almost equal number of chocolates. So I give 2 chocolates to the 3rd child(which has 3 chocolates). This makes the chocolate distribution 5,5,5,1